# How can I disable / ignore proxy settings from inside a kubernetes pod only for requests directed to kubernetes services?

Tags: kubernetes, http-proxy

I have set these environment variables inside my pod named **main_pod**.

```
$ env
HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.com
http_proxy=http://myproxy.com
```

I also have another dynamic pod in pattern **sub_pod-{number}** which has a service attached to it called `sub_pod-{number}`.

So, if I add `NO_PROXY=sub_pod-1` environment variable in **main_pod**, request with URL `http://sub_pod-1:5000/health_check` will run successfully as it won't be directed through proxy which is fine.

But I want this process to be dynamic. `sub_pod_45` might spawn at runtime and `sub_pod-1` might get destroyed. Is there any better way to handle this rather than updating `NO_PROXY` for every pod creation / destruction ?

Is there any resource / network policy / egress rule from which I can tell pod that if domain name belongs to kubernetes service, do not route it through proxy server?

Or can I simply use regex or glob patterns in `NO_PROXY` env variable like `NO_PROXY=sub_pod-*` ?

Edited

**Result of nslookup**

```
root@tmp-shell:/# nslookup sub_pod-1
Server:     10.43.0.10
Address:    10.43.0.10#53

Name:   sub_pod-1.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.43.22.139
```

#### When `no_proxy=cluster.local`,

**Proxy bypassed when requested with FQDN**

`res = requests.get('http://sub_pod-1.default.svc.cluster.local:5000')`

**Proxy didn't bypass when requested with service name only**

`res = requests.get('http://sub_pod-1:5000')`  # I want this to work

I would not want to ask my developers to change the application to use FQDN.

Is there any way cluster can identify if URL resolves to a service present within the network and if it happens do not route the request to proxy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries that support the `http_proxy` environment variable generally also support a matching `no_proxy` that names things that shouldn't be proxied.  The exact syntax seems to [vary across languages and libraries](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/01/27/we-need-to-talk-no-proxy/#no_proxy) but it does seem to be universal that setting `no_proxy=example.com` causes `anything.example.com` to not be proxied either.

This is relevant because the [Kubernetes DNS system](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#dns-records) creates its names in a domain based on the cluster name, by default `cluster.local`.  The canonical form of a Service DNS name, for example, is `service-name.namespace-name.svc.cluster.local.`, where `service-name` and `namespace-name` are the names of the corresponding Kubernetes objects.

I suspect this means it would work to do two things:

1. Set an environment variable `no_proxy=cluster.local`; and
2. Make sure to use the FQDN form when calling other services, `service.namespace.svc.cluster.local`.

Pods have similar naming, but are in a `pod.cluster.local` subdomain.  The `cluster.local` value is configurable at a cluster level and it may be different in your environment.

Comment: I have edited the post. Please check once. Your method works but it means that I have to change the code at application level. I want to prioritise handling this at Ops level.

Comment: I'd hope you could implement this by only changing the environment variables or ConfigMap content that specifies the host names; you shouldn't have to change code (implying the host names need to be configurable in the code).

Comment: After doing more research on this, I found out that we don't even need full FQDN, we could shorten the URL and only use service_name.namespace-name URL format and then in NO_PROXY we can add namespace-name.